# Delay eventListener

Tags: javascript, this, settimeout, addeventlistener

In JavaScript, I have an element (which is an input tag).

This code :

```
element.addEventListener("focus", function () {
    this.parentNode.parentNode.style.outline = this.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.ans_outline;
});
```

When the input is focused, outline is changed immediately.

My question is : how could I delay this event ?

I've tried :

```
element.addEventListener("focus", function () {
    setTimeout(function(node) {
        node.parentNode.parentNode.style.outline = node.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.ans_outline;
    }(this), 1000)
});
```

.. But it doesn't work :(

Comment: you are calling the function inside of the timeout, hence why it is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
element.addEventListener("focus", function () {
    var node = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        node.parentNode.parentNode.style.outline = node.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.ans_outline;
    }, 1000)
});
```

First argument of [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) function is function you want to execute (do not call this function directly).

You can store reference to `this` in `node` variable and then use it inside your timed out function (see [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Closure))

Answer (score 2):

Remove the reference to the `this` and give it this way:

```
element.addEventListener("focus", function () {
    $this = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.parentNode.parentNode.style.outline = $this.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.ans_outline;
    }, 1000)
});
```