# How to run a function after a specific time that is triggered by an event like click (vanilla JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
square.addEventListener('click', funct1);
function funct1(){
    setTimeout(funct2(), 5000);
}
```

I am trying to execute `funct2` after 5 seconds after clicking but for some reason it isn't working.

Comment: Remove the parenthesis after `funct2` when you pass it as a parameter to `setTimeout`.

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202824/delay-eventlistener